# Discord.js my command for 'help' is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically i've made a help command for my discord.js bot and I tried implementing a page system into the bot but I have two issues. 1: Whenever I react to an emoji the bot lags and sometimes it won't change pages, and 2: The commands won't split into two halves so I'm not able to display two halves of the commands onto seperate pages so that the first embed isn't so long. Here's my code

````
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const {
    stripIndents
} = require("common-tags");
const {
    getMember,
    formatDate
} = require("../../functions.js");
const viewPerms = require("../../cmdviewperms.json");

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "help",
        aliases: ["?"],
        category: "Info",
        description: "Returns help information",
        usage: "!help",
    },
    run: (client, message, args) => {
        let cmds = client.commands;
        let allUsers = {
            Everyone: [],
            ADMINISTRATOR: []
        }

        for (let value of cmds) {
            let category = value[1].config.category;
            viewPerms.forEach(e => {
                if (e.cmdGroup.toLowerCase() == category.toLowerCase()) {
                    //console.log(`CATEGORY OF ${value[1].config.name} IS ${e.cmdGroup}`)
                    if (value[1].config.bypassUsers) {
                        value[1].config.bypassUsers.forEach(x => {
                            //console.log(`${value[1].config.name} ADDED TO ${x}; CMDGROUP: ${e.cmdGroup}`)
                            allUsers[x].push(value[1].config);
                        })
                    } else {
                        e.AllowedUsers.forEach(x => {
                            //console.log(`${value[1].config.name} ADDED TO ${x}; CMDGROUP: ${e.cmdGroup}`)
                            allUsers[x].push(value[1].config);
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        let adminEmbedText = "";
        let userEmbedText = "";
        allUsers.ADMINISTRATOR.forEach(e => {
            let name = e.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.name.slice(1, e.name.length);
            adminEmbedText = `${adminEmbedText} ${name}\n`;
        })

        allUsers.Everyone.forEach(e => {
            let name = e.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.name.slice(1, e.name.length);
            userEmbedText = `${userEmbedText} ${name}\n`;
        })

        //const embedHalf = Math.ceil(userEmbedText.length / 2);
        // var firsthalf = userEmbedText.lastIndexOf(' ', embedHalf);
        // var secondhalf = userEmbedText.indexOf(' ', embedHalf + 1);

        const embedhalf = Math.ceil(userEmbedText.split(" "))
        var firsthalf = userEmbedText.lastIndexOf(' ', embedhalf);
        var secondhalf = userEmbedText.indexOf(' ', embedhalf + 1);

        let page = 1 
        let pages = [firsthalf, secondhalf]


        let adminEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Commands")
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setDescription(adminEmbedText)
            .setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
        let userEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Commands")
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setDescription(userEmbedText)
            .setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)


                //console.log(sh)
                //console.log(fh)
        if (args.length == 0) {
            if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.author.send(adminEmbed);
            return message.channel.send(userEmbed).then(msg => {

                msg.react('◀️').then(r => {
                    msg.react('▶️')

                    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                        return ['◀️', '▶️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                    };

                    const back = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
                        timeout: 60000
                    });
                    const forw = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
                        timeout: 60000
                    })

                    back.on('collect', (r, u) => {
                        if (page === 1) return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
                        page--
                        userEmbed.setDescription(userEmbedText)
                        userEmbed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
                        msg.edit(userEmbed)
                        r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
                    })
                
                    forw.on('collect', (r, u) => {
                        if (page === pages.length) return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
                        page++
                        userEmbed.setDescription(userEmbedText)
                        userEmbed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
                        msg.edit(userEmbed)
                        r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
                    })
                  })
                })
    
        } else {
            let cmd = args.join(" ");
            let cmdFound = false;
            let embed = "No command found!";
            if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                allUsers.ADMINISTRATOR.forEach(e => {
                    if (cmd.toLowerCase() == e.name.toLowerCase()) {
                        let name = e.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.name.slice(1, e.name.length);
                        embed = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle(`Command: ${name}`)
                            .setColor("RANDOM")
                            .setDescription(`Name: ${name} \n\n > Description: ${e.description} \n\n> Category: ${e.category} \n\n > Usage: ${e.usage}`);
                    }
                })
            }
            allUsers.Everyone.forEach(e => {
                if (cmd.toLowerCase() == e.name.toLowerCase()) {
                    let name = e.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.name.slice(1, e.name.length);
                    embed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(`Command: ${e.name}`)
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription(`Name: ${name} \n\n > Description: ${e.description} \n\n> Category: ${e.category} \n\n > Usage: ${e.usage}`);
                }
            })
            return message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see skimming over this code is the use of `Math.ceil()` on the array you get from a `split()`, which doesn't make any sense as `Math.ceil()` only takes numbers. This is what's causing your help text to not split into two pages. Further down, your two message reaction collectors `forw` and `back` are both looking for the same reactions, because you created them using the same filter. Both of the callbacks execute every time either reaction is hit, because both reactions pass the filter. That makes it a tossup whether the page actually switches or not. Make the collectors use two different filters, each one only looking for the correct reaction. I haven't looked over the code line by line, so there might be more issues, but those are the two main issues I see.

Comment: Alright could you explain how i would use split() though?

Comment: @ColdtQ the split() function takes a string and returns an array of split apart substrings. For example, you'd use split() to split the incoming command into a primary command and arguments. It would be message.content.split(" ") if your bot takes commands like "!help something something_else", which would return an array ["!help", "something", "something_else"]. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Alright hey do you think you could add me on discord as I have a couple more issues and Its a harder to communicate on here, Cold tQ#0001 is my tag